# Canvas' fillRect function ignores await

Tags: javascript, canvas, async-await

I have a problem with the `fillRect` canvas function: I use the `setFillStyle` function to either set the `fillStyle` to a rgb value or to an image source. The image will be fetched using the image's `onload` method. Since I want to make sure that the following call to `fillRect` will be using this `fillStyle` I made it return a promise and I set its caller to `async` and awaiting `setFillStyle`.

It appears that `fillRect` ignores the `await` since sometimes (when the image doesn't get fetched in time) it draws a `#000000` color (which is default) over the entire canvas while sometimes (when the image luckily gets fetched in time) it draws the pattern generated of the image.

```js
async fillArea() {
  const { width, height } = this.context.canvas;
  await this.setFillStyle()
    .catch(({ src }) => console.error(`Failed to load image: ${src}`));
  this.context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
},
setFillStyle() {
  const { type, value = '', src = '', repeat = '' } = this.hideOptions;
  this.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  if (type === 'color') return this.context.fillStyle = value;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve({ src });
    img.onerror = () => reject({ src });

    img.src = src;
    this.context.fillStyle = this.context.createPattern(img, repeat);
  });
},
```

I also tried to not use `async await` and fall back to `.then` which didn't lead to a different behavior:

```js
fillArea() {
  const { width, height } = this.context.canvas;
  this.setFillStyle()
    .catch(({ src }) => console.error(`Failed to load image: ${src}`))
    .then(() => this.context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height));
},
```

How can this be resolved since I can't get my head around it?

Comment: How often does `if (type === 'color') return this.context.fillStyle = value;` happen? You should always return a promise, not return a promise one time and a value the other time. Not 100% sure yet that's the root problem here, but that's the first thing i'd check.

Comment: What result do you get? Does the catch get called? And indd, what Shilly says.

Comment: @Shilly goo point I will try that. EDIT: this did not fix the problem.

Comment: @Trace if the source of the image is a valid source it will not catch instead it will actually set the `fillStyle` correctly but the rect is already drawn (with `#000000`). If the source is not valid the catch will get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem this code has is that I tried to create the pattern before the actual fetching of the image was resolved. The `createPattern` function defaulted to using `#000000` instead of the image to create the pattern.

Corrected code would look like this:

```js
async fillArea() {
  const { width, height } = this.context.canvas;
  await this.setFillStyle()
    .catch(({ src }) => console.error(`Failed to load image: ${src}`));
  this.context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
},
setFillStyle() {
  const { type, value = '', src = '', repeat = '' } = this.hideOptions;
  this.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  if (type === 'color') return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this.context.fillStyle = value));
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      this.context.fillStyle = this.context.createPattern(img, repeat);
      resolve(img);
    };
    img.onerror = () => reject({ src });
    img.src = src;
  });
},
```